# rails LoadError: cannot load such file -- lib/scraper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

In my rails app, I have a rake task that scrapes data from another webpage. I want to move the method functionality out of the rake task into a ruby class or module. To do, I have the rake task in lib/tasks, then scraper.rb in lib. In the rake task, I have require 'lib/scraper' but this throws an error.

Here is my rake task:

```
require "lib/scraper"
namespace :some_namespace do
    desc "A description"
    task :scrape_info => :environment do
        scraper = Scraper.new
        scraper.scrape_info
    end
end
```

And the ruby scraper class:

```
require 'mechanize'
class Scraper
    def scrape_info
        mechanize = Mechanize.new

        # Scrape players from fox sports
        url = "someurl"

        # do some other stuff
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look as follows.

**`lib/scraper.rb`:**

```
require 'mechanize'

module Scraper
  class Scraper
    def scrape_info
    end
  end
end
```

**`lib/tasks/some_namespace.rake`:**

```
namespace :some_namespace do
  task some_task :environment do
    include Scraper
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! When I tried this, I got an error uninitialized constant Scraper. Any idea why?

Comment: Probably because it isn't eager loaded. What version of rails are you on?

Comment: Put this into 'config/applications.rb'
config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"

Comment: I'm on rails 5 - tried that, I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: Yes I did, although does the server even need to be running to run a rake task?

Comment: No it doesn't, I didn't read that is was a rake tast. Is your file named scraper.rb in lib folder?

Comment: @NathanLauer I updated the answer. The include has to happen below the 'task...' line, since the Rails environment isn't loaded until after that point in rake tasks. Hope that solves it.